# how to train chatbot with emoticons as input data?

Tags: chatbot, emoticons, chatterbot

I am using chatterbot python library & developed a chatbot.
It is giving answer correctly & quickly.
now i am trying to train chatbot with smileys & images & emoticons.

Can someone help me here?
i tried searching solution but didn't help.
Yes I am not expecting the code ,I am expecting a good start point.
I used emoji library but I am looking for better Library & better approach.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Dont just expect people to write code for you when you are not providing any code of yours or shown any effort.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want emojis mixed with words? Or just purely emojis?

Just make a normal data input with the emojis id#

https://emojipedia.org/squared-id/

https://emojipedia.org/emojione/